# Continuous function for $I \equiv \left(x_0 - \frac{1}{n},x_0 +\frac{1}{n}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that a function $f\colon \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous at a point at $x_0$ and that $f\left(x_0\right)>0$. Prove that there is an interval $I \equiv \left(x_0 - \frac{1}{n},x_0 +\frac{1}{n}\right)$, where $n$ is a natural number such that $f\left(x\right)>0$ for all $x$ in $I$. $\left(Hint:\text{Argue by contradiction}.\right)$

I have done this problem on two separate occasions, and have done it incorrectly both times. Can somebody give an outline of the proof. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

If $f$ is continuous at $x_0$ and $f(x_0)>0$ then, by definition, for $\epsilon=1/2 f(x_0)$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that

$$|x-x_0|<\delta \implies |f(x)-f(x_0)|<\frac{f(x_0)}{2}.$$

**Edit**

Working with your definition. If $f(x)$ is not positive in the interval $ \left(x_0 - \frac{1}{n},x_0 +\frac{1}{n}\right)$ then there exists $ x_n\left(x_0 - \frac{1}{n},x_0 +\frac{1}{n}\right)$ such that $f(x_n)\le 0.$ Now, the sequence $x_n$ converges to $x_0.$ Since $f$ is continuous it is

$$0<f(x_0)=\lim_nf(x_n)\le 0,$$ since $f(x_n)\le 0,\forall n\in\mathbb{N},$ which gives you a contradiction.

Comment: When I did this the only definition of continuous that I had was if $x_n\rightarrow x_0$ then $f\left(x_n\right)\rightarrow f\left(x_0\right).$ Can you think of a way to do it with this approach?